# CSP blocking fineuploader thumbnail after uploading to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, http-headers, blob, fine-uploader, content-security-policy

I'm having problems with my **Content-Security-Policy** which is being handled by the **[bepsvpt/secure-headers](https://github.com/BePsvPT/secure-headers)** package.

After uploading a file successfully to an S3 server with [**Fineuploader**](https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/quickstart/01-getting-started.html) the plugin tries to load the thumbnail image dispatching a request like this:

`blob:http://b2b.local/085a1b81-0513-47a8-a334-fbc4eca4b365`

This request is being blocked by my CSP, which prevents the thumbnail from showing and the following message in the console:

> Refused to load the image
>   'blob:http://b2b.local/085a1b81-0513-47a8-a334-fbc4eca4b365' because
>   it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src
>   'self' http://*.google-analytics.com
>   http://businessmarketplace.s3.amazonaws.com http://b2b.dev
>   http://placehold.it http://mediaweek.com.au data:".

My CSP configuration goes like this:

```
<?php
$protocol = 'https://';
if (! isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'off') {
    $protocol = 'http://';
}

return [
    'x-content-type-options' => 'nosniff',
    'x-download-options' => 'noopen',
    'x-frame-options' => 'sameorigin',
    'x-permitted-cross-domain-policies' => 'none',
    'x-xss-protection' => '1; mode=block',
    'referrer-policy' => 'unsafe-url',
    'hsts' => [
        'enable' => env('SECURITY_HEADER_HSTS_ENABLE', false),
        'max-age' => 31536000,
        'include-sub-domains' => true,
    ],
    'hpkp' => [
        'hashes' => false,
        'include-sub-domains' => false,
        'max-age' => 15552000,
        'report-only' => false,
        'report-uri' => null,
    ],
    'custom-csp' => env('SECURITY_HEADER_CUSTOM_CSP', null),
    'csp' => [
        'report-only' => false,
        'report-uri' => env('CONTENT_SECURITY_POLICY_REPORT_URI', false),
        'upgrade-insecure-requests' => false,
        'default-src' => [
            'allow' => [
                'player.vimeo.com',
            ],
            'self' => true,
        ],
        'script-src' => [
            'allow' => [
                $protocol.'ajax.googleapis.com',
                $protocol.'code.jquery.com',
                $protocol.'www.googletagmanager.com',
                $protocol.'www.google-analytics.com',
                $protocol.'www.google.com',
                $protocol.'www.gstatic.com',
                $protocol.'sachinchoolur.github.io',
                $protocol.'cdnjs.cloudflare.com',                
                $protocol.'*.addthis.com',
                $protocol.'*.addthisedge.com',
                $protocol.'*.facebook.com',
            ],
            'self' => true,
            'unsafe-inline' => true,
            'unsafe-eval' => true,
            'data' => true,
        ],
        'frame-src' => [
            'allow' => [
                'player.vimeo.com',                
                $protocol.'www.google.com',
                $protocol.'*.addthis.com',
                $protocol.'*.addthisedge.com',
            ]
        ],
        'style-src' => [
            'allow' => [
                $protocol.'fonts.googleapis.com',
                $protocol.'sachinchoolur.github.io',
                $protocol.'code.jquery.com',
                $protocol.'*.addthis.com',
                $protocol.'*.addthisedge.com',
            ],
            'self' => true,
            'unsafe-inline' => true,
        ],
        'img-src' => [
            'allow' => [
                $protocol.'*.google-analytics.com',
                $protocol.'businessmarketplace.s3.amazonaws.com',                
                $protocol.'placehold.it',
                $protocol.'mediaweek.com.au',
            ],
            'self' => true,
            'data' => true,
            'blob' => true,
        ],
        'font-src' => [
            'allow' => [
                $protocol.'fonts.gstatic.com',
            ],
            'self' => true,
            'data' => true,
        ],
        'object-src' => [
            'allow' => [],
            'self' => true,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Notice I'm setting the options self, data and blob for the **img-src** policy to **true**.

When removing all configuration for the  **img-src** policy and setting **default-src** to **`*`** I get the plugin to display the thumbnails properly but basically I'm missing the whole point by allowing all type of requests.

What is wrong in my configuration that prevents my thumbnails from loading when the 'self' and blob: attributes are set to **true**?

Answer (score 1):

After testing with my team different configurations we found out that you can use the **`allow`** array to specify also directives like **`'self'`** or **`blob:`** so we are setting the **`img-src`** directive to:

```
   'img-src' => [
        'allow' => [
            "'self'", 'blob:',
            $protocol.'*.google-analytics.com',
            $protocol.'businessmarketplace.s3.amazonaws.com',                
            $protocol.'placehold.it',
            $protocol.'mediaweek.com.au',
        ],
    ],
```

And now the policy is allowing requests like **`blob:http://b2b.local/hash`**